# how to find out the actual hardware configuration of my PC in software level?

Tags: benchmarking

without actually opening the PC chassis and looking at the hardware with naked eyes, how to find out the actual hardware configuration of my PC in software level?
Could the software used to test the benchmark reveal incorrect hardware info?

Assume somebody dishonest has swapped my hardware with inferior one and changed the hardware info to scam me.

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty: *Start > Run > MSINFO32.exe*

Now if you mean that the hardware ID is somehow being spoofed to Windows and doesn't report correctly either... you've really got problems big enough to warrant opening it up.  That said, there are tons of benchmark solutions out there, but you'll need very specific data to compare with.

Comment: Also: cpu-z and gpu-z i think are both freeware and check the hardware directly.

Answer (score 0):

A utility called Speccy will tell you all hardware in the system. It can be found at http://www.piriform.com. I've had reasonable success with all the utilities they write.